# Memory Allocation Error with C? Code works when unused variable is defined; crashes otherwise

Tags: c

I'm a novice C programmer and am completely stuck on debugging a program that relies on the CFITSIO package [sorry in advance if I get the terminology wrong below].   I have two fits that I am reading in: 1. "BFmask.fits", 2. "DFmask.fits".   These are two files that either have a 1 or a 0 as elements.

These are defined as double precision pointers as below:
double *maskdark,*maskbright;

Memory allocation is as follows:

```
maskdark=malloc(size*sizeof(double)); //dark mask
maskbright=malloc(size*sizeof(double)); //bright mask
```

where "size" is a long variable with a value of 490000

THE PROBLEM: When I execute the program, it apparently does not properly read in BFmask.fits or DFmask.fits (i.e. does not properly read in entries for maskbright or maskdark).

HOWEVER, when I declare a third variable called 'mask' (i.e. double *mask;), then the program DOES execute properly.

1. What is the cause and solution to this problem?
2. How do I avoid similar ones in the future?

I have checked dozens of times to make sure this variable is not used anywhere in the program.  This makes no sense to me.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 //For declaration of open, close
 #include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <time.h>
 //GSL Matrix STuff
 #include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
 #include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
 #include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
 #include <gsl/gsl_eigen.h>
 #include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
 //CFITSIO
 #include <fitsio.h>
int main ()
{
long sizetotdm,cmwfsbrightindex,cmwfsdarkindex;
long size,sizex,sizey;
double *maskdark,*maskbright;
//double *mask; //if I uncomment this, then the program works   properly somehow
fitsfile *fptr;
float nullval;
int  status, anynull;

cmwfsbrightindex=0;
cmwfsdarkindex=0;
sizex=700; sizey=700; size=sizex*sizey;

/* Define Masks for Dark Field and Bright Field */
maskdark=malloc(size*sizeof(double)); //dark mask
maskbright=malloc(size*sizeof(double)); //bright mask

/* Read in Dark and Bright Field Mask files */
sprintf(s_file,"./06_21_19_mask/BFmask.fits");
fits_open_file(&fptr,s_file,READONLY,&status);
   fits_read_img(fptr,TDOUBLE,1,size,&nullval,maskbright,&anynull,&status);


sprintf(s_file,"./06_21_19_mask/DFmask.fits");
fits_open_file(&fptr,s_file,READONLY,&status);
fits_read_img(fptr,TDOUBLE,1,size,&nullval,maskdark,&anynull,&status);

for (i=0;i<size; i++)
 {
  if (*(maskbright+i)==1)
   {
     cmwfsbrightindex+=1;
      }
  if (*(maskdark+i)==1)
   {
     cmwfsdarkindex+=1;
      }
  }

printf("the number of pixels is %ld %ld     \n",cmwfsbrightindex,cmwfsdarkindex);
}
```

Results should be ...

```
the number of pixels is 24212 24952 //this happens when I define an unused variable
```

The results are ...

```
the number of pixels is 0 0  //this happens when I comment out the unused variable
```

Comment: Symptoms look like undefined behavior. E.g. array index-out-of-bounds or something similar. Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can reproduce the error in full. In particular, instead of saying how you've declared variables, just declare them in the example. That way we can see all little details in the example that may matter.

Comment: `double *maskdark,*maskbright;` are *uninitialised* variables, and passing then to functions in the way you do cannot initialise them. Yet the code is dereferencing them. You mention using `malloc` to assign memory pointers to them, but that does not appear in the code. A [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is essential, otherwise it is guess work, as the damage may occur somewhere unrelated.

Comment: I thought I did but now see that the memory allocation lines for maskbright and maskdark were missing.  I added them.   Does that help?

Comment: You'll need to `#include` some library headers, but even then the code will not compile. There is too much missing. The MRE is a complete working example that can be copy/pasted compiled and run. The act of preparing this may show you where the problems are.

Comment: What these kind folks are trying to tell you is that we can't take the code from your question, put it in a text file, and compile it. They want either all of the code or the smallest amount of code that reproduces the problem. However, most people find that once they reduce their code to a small enough size to post here, the problem becomes obvious.

Comment: Did you know that `*(maskdark+i)` can be rewritten as `maskdark[i]`? It's an array so using array syntax is clearer in my opinion. Same thing with `maskbright`.

Comment: Okay, is that close to what you need to reproduce the problem?   I could just send you the code in its entirety but it includes a lot of extraneous information.

Comment: It's not supposed to be "close", it's supposed to reproduce the problem exactly. And you should remove all parts that are not relevant for this purpose.

Comment: Try compiling with `-Wall` and `-Werror`. Also, you should check the return value of `fits_open_file`. If `fits_read_img` returns a value, you might need to check that too.

Comment: There are several values that you should check.. both malloc calls, for example. Check if those pointers are NULL or not, i.e. if malloc is returning an address or not. You may also want to check if `fits_open_file(&fptr,s_file,READONLY,&status);` fails or not, and the same for `fits_read_img()`.

Comment: Hi David: thanks, that may have solved the problem.  -Wall -Werror  identified 18 "error: unused variable" messages.   After removing all of the unused variables, the program compiles and seems to not trigger the error that occurred (i.e. the output is now correct).   I still don't understand *why* this happened, though.

Comment: Unused variables do not cause errors (unless very large which break the stack). All you have done is to shift the bump under the carpet, without finding its cause. Some action is corrupting other variables, and quite often this is caused by using uninitialised variables (which can give a compiler warning) or indexing beyond the bounds of an array (which the compiler probably does not detect - except for initialising data at the point of definition of the array). Some ways to approach this are a) divide and conquer, b) debugger, c) a memory analysis tool.

Comment: If you are still worried, try compiling with `-fstack-protector` or `-fstack-protector-all`. These might identify buffer overflows.

Comment: Weather Vane - Thanks.   Just so I understand [again sorry, C syntax knowledge = very limited], you're saying there probably *is* a variable somewhere that I have defined [e.g. as double, long, etc.] and try to use but for which I have not properly allocated memory? I had been using gdb for debugging [but here again my experience is extremely limited].